# How to enable dev tool again on specific event in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable the dev tool again which is disabled by this code in jquery. I found many solutions but those were not worked for me.

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Enable:

```
 function eableDevTool(){
  //Do something to enable dev tool again
 }
```

Comment: Use a boolean flag to determine whether or not you should call `preventDefault()`. Also note that your code doesn't stop access to dev tools - you can do it through the browser menu as well as the context menu

Comment: The context menu isn't a dev tool - at least, I'd have said its primary purpose is giving non-dev users access to normal features like *Back* and *Forward* navigation and the clipboard, etc. Anyway, what's wrong with `$(document).unbind("contextmenu")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to add and remove events easily

```js
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(e) { // wax on
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#test').on('click', function() {
    $(document).off("contextmenu");         // wax off
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Turn on context menu</button>
```